# Creating CSS button state styles for elements with a particular class

Tags: html, css

How can I define button states on the following? Am I missing something obvious here? I've tried the following and have had no luck :

```css
button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt {
  width: 100%;
}

button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt:hover {
  width: 100% !important;
  display: block !important;
  background-color: #10aa0b;
  color: #ffffff;
}

button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt:visited {
  width: 100% !important;
  display: block !important;
  background-color: #10aa0b;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" style="display: block !important; background-color: #ff0a0a; color:#ffffff;">Add to cart</button>
```

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "button states". For instance, `button` elements do not have a "visited" state.

Comment: That's what I think I am confusing. I'd like the hover color to remain once the button is clicked.

Comment: You'd have to use standard classes (not pseudo-classes) and change them with JavaScript. You'd then have to store that state in a persistent way for page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment you should use `:active` rather than `:visited`

Comment: I'm not sure the active state would persist long enough to meet the OP's specs.